# Keyboard (mapping) issue

Tags: keyboard

The **SPACEBAR** key press produces **PAGE DOWN** key press and then **SPACEBAR** key press. This is super annoying, especially when I work with text processors (it moves the cursor at the end of the page and then produces blank). There is similar problem with **RETURN** key, an extra key press is a **PAGE UP** in this case. I'm not sure if my issue is Ubuntu related or just Linux related. It could be a hardware error too because I dropped my laptop (it started to malfunction a week later after the fall). Here is output of `xev`:

SPACEBAR

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 11588814, (-133,266), root:(1067,409),
    state 0x0, keycode 117 (keysym 0xff56, Next), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

 KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 11588814, (-133,266), root:(1067,409),
    state 0x0, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,

    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 11588869, (-133,266), root:(1067,409),
    state 0x0, keycode 117 (keysym 0xff56, Next), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 11588869, (-133,266), root:(1067,409),
    state 0x0, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

RETURN

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 11664873, (903,592), root:(903,644),
    state 0x0, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 11664873, (903,592), root:(903,644),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
"   XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 11664941, (903,592), root:(903,644),
    state 0x0, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 11664941, (903,592), root:(903,644),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What could be wrong? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm that it's not OS related issue. The same problem appears in BIOS. I'm wondering how to capture a key stroke and prevent event handler to fire in Linux.